# Javafx: how to change the size of .chart-legend-item-symbol in css?

Tags: css, javafx, size, legend, symbols

I'm relatively new to Javafx and completely new to CSS.
Right now I would like to export a chart that I created in Javafx to a png file and as I would like to have a high quality picture I changed some of the settings of my CSS sheet so that things like font-sizes are bigger now.

I managed to change almost all the parameters but I have one remaining problem: I found no way of changing the size of the chart legend symbols. 
Oracle provides a JavaFX reference guide and I found that I should be able to change the settings in style class .chart-legend-item-symbol.  (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

I also found a tutorial, also from Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm), where they say: "By default, legend symbols look like circles, because they are declared as rounded rectangles with a 5-pixel height, 5-pixel width, and 5-pixel radius."

So my question is: is there a parameter that I can use to change that 5px size of the rectangle? Or do I need to completely redefine a rectangle with another size here and if so - how can I do that?

I feel kind of stupid, as I didn't understand the syntax of CSS completely until now, but I didn't find a solution for that problem by asking google.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: nobody out there who has an idea? :-/

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at jewelsea's answer here:
[Controlling symbols, etc. in lineCharts inline programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287484/controlling-symbols-etc-in-linecharts-inline-programmatically) .

You can access any legend symbol via:

```
.default-color0.chart-legend-item-symbol{}
.default-color1.chart-legend-item-symbol{}
.default-color2.chart-legend-item-symbol{}
```

Maybe there are better ways to achieve this, but you can set a custom background-image as legend-item-symbol and change its size:

```
.default-color0.chart-legend-item-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-size: 5px;
    -fx-background-image: url('../Icons/rectangle.png');
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center; 
}
```

Or use this approach here (Custom Legend Symbol for Pie Chart):
https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1422628

Answer (score -1):

```
// For Line chart you can use

.default-color0.chart-line-symbol {
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
```

or you can simply change to area chart , by replacing `-line-` to `-area-`