# Setting LineChart symbol via code without css in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

This question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287484/controlling-symbols-etc-in-linecharts-inline-programmatically) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153370/how-to-set-specific-color-to-javafx-xychart-series).

The user can pick a custom color, after that I need to display the line chart in this color. The lines do work as described in the second link:

```java
String rgb = String.format("%d, %d, %d",
        (int) (user.getColor().getRed() * 255),
        (int) (user.getColor().getGreen() * 255),
        (int) (user.getColor().getBlue() * 255));
series.nodeProperty().get().setStyle("-fx-stroke: rgba(" + rgb + ", 1);");
```

I'm not able to change the symbols of the users chart. With css you would do this:

```css
.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #e9967a, white; }
.default-color1.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #f0e68c, white; }
.default-color2.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #dda0dd, white; }
```

I can't do this, because the user can choose any color possible. Is there a workaround?

---

I tried this, but this throws a `NullPointerException`:

```java
chart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-line-symbol")
     .setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(" + rgb + ", 1), white;");
```

Adding a `Platform.runLater(() -> chart.lo....)` gets rid of the `NullPointerException` (I don't understand why) but only turns some points in the correct color, and never the legend.

Comment: CSS lookups only work after CSS has been applied, which by default happens on the first layout pass; this explains why you get a null pointer exception which is removed by using `Platform.runLater()`. A more robust way is to call `applyCSS()` on the scene before performing the lookup. But the solution in my answer avoids lookups entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a series of "looked-up colors", which you can then change programmatically.

In the external CSS file, set these to some default value, and define your background colors depending on them:

```css
.line-chart {
    symbol-color0: #e9967a ;
    symbol-color1: #f0e68c ;
    symbol-color2: #dda0dd ;
    /* ... */
}

.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: symbol-color0, white; }
.default-color1.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: symbol-color1, white; }
.default-color2.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: symbol-color2, white; }
```

Then in your Java code you can redefine those to arbitrary colors:

```
Color[] colors = getUserDefinedColors();

StringBuilder style = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++) {
    style.append("symbol-color")
         .append(i)
         .append(": ")
         .append(convertToWebString(colors[i]))
         .append("; ");
}
myLineChart.setStyle(style.toString());
```

with something like

```
private String convertToWebString(Color c) {
    int r = (int)(255*c.getRed());
    int g = (int)(255*c.getGreen());
    int b = (int)(255*c.getBlue());
    return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
}
```